# SSO oauth2 revalidate login for higher security in specific clients

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am currently working at an application which will contain sensitive data and therefor I want to revalidate that the user is still correct after the application session was terminated.

Now I can terminate the session in my App but spring boot will just log me in again (without any validation) as I am still logged in at the SSO (Keycloak) Endpoint. Is there a way to force a user to revalidate the SSO login for specific clients when the current client session expired?

A solution would probably be to use another realm with a quick logout, but then I see a problem to keep the users between realms in sync.
This is my first time working with SSO and Keycloak / Spring-boot-security.
My current configuration for Spring-Boot is:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.master.client-id=my-Client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.master.client-secret=<secret>
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.master.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.master.issuer-uri=https://localhost/realms/master
```

And the code:

```java
    public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    //For Healthchecks
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasRole("special")
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login();
            return http.build();
        }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you logout your user from the OIDC Provider (aka OP, aka authorization server) too when you invalidate user session on your Relying Party (aka RP, aka OAuth2 client)? This is done with [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) and Spring provides with `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` for that (provided that your OP complies with the spec, which is the case for Keycloak but not Auth0 or Cognito for instance, in which case you'll have to refer to your OP doc and write a LogoutSuccessHandler by yourself)

Comment: @ch4mp sorry for the late reply! My intent is only a "logout" / reverification for specific clients. So secure client S and open client O can both use the master realm. User U is logged into the master realm. Now he accesses client O without any need to revalidate that he indeed is the correct user. With the OIDC login still valid the user opens client S, but as the security is higher and he currently has no valid JWT Token. Therefor the user has to "login" against the OICD again to verify that he is user U and not anyone else. Is there a way to do this, without much client site management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case I was able to Edit the Default browser flow in Keycloak.

Duplicating the flow, and delete that user can login via cookies (just keep the login form).
Setting the new flow as Browser flow for my Application forces the user to login every time the Application Session ends.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, it seems that you don't trust your OP to be sure that the user actually is who he pretends to be. That's an issue you can't sort on client side. If you want to improve security, add multi-factor authentication on the authorization server and use different clients for different front-ends.

The only point you can address from the client side, is to trigger the OP logout from the client if a user thinks he logs out from the system (SSO and all the clients connected to it) when he actually only invalidates his session on one of your front-ends. A new login will not change anything in that case.

You should have in mind that your user browser has 3 different sessions:

- on the OIDC Provider (Keycloak)
- on the *secured* backend
- on the *opened* one

You should also be aware that the user is not authenticated on clients. It is authenticated on the OP. This is even the essence of SSO: there is a single user representation across clients of a single OP. So if user is authenticated on the OP, his ID is valid for all the clients.

Clients maintain "authorizations to act on behalf of a user authenticated on an authorization server" (this being a bit long, was called `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` in Spring framework). It is saved in session and contains the user representation from the OP and tokens, along with a representation of the client config used to get it (client and registration details).

Now, your use case: when an OAuth2 client triggers an authorization-code flow, if the user already has a session opened on the authorization server, the authorization code is returned silently and the client can fetch tokens and instantiate an `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` to store using an `OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` (provided that the user already gave consent for the  requested scopes to that client, but it's another story).

Options if you don't want that to happen:

- logout the user from the OP when you invalidate a user session on your clients. This is [RP-Initiated Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html) and Spring provides with `OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler` for that (if the OP complies with spec, which Keycloak does). Just hook it in your client logout with `http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository));`
- change the OP (use another realm or Keycloak instance)

Be aware that invalidating the session on a client configured with RP initiated logout will invalidate the user session on the OP, but that this will be cascaded back from the OP to other clients only if Back Channel logout is implemented and configured on both sides.

Back channel logout is not implemented in spring. I have an experimental implementation, but it is not published yet (maybe next week, once the next version of spring-cloud is released).